# How to create search engine in PHP or ajax?

Tags: search

I want to create a search engine for checking company name for Ireland like http://www.vision-net.ie/freeSearch or https://search.cro.ie/company/ but no idea how this search engine works? if somebody expert here then help me to create search engine for checking company name.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: They have a database full of records and will select any searches similar to (Levenshtein fuzzy search)or synonym to the record. The client (browser) does an ajax/query to the search page on the server side (PHP/ASP/JSP/etc.) and will do a database search and then either return to ajax a JSON search result or display a new search result page rendered server-side. This question isn't specific enough to be on SO, so more personal research is needed.

Comment: the site above mentioned shows same result with same format while searching company so I believe the search engine is not searching from their database their is also another website http://solocheck.ie which also gives result in same format whats the reason that all three web gives the result in sam format, the difference is only about the styles not the results

Answer (score 0):

Here is an introduction tutorial that shows the searching capabilities of PHP and ajax, working alongside a MySQL Database

First create the html form.. you should execute this on a localhost WAMP environment to observe the effects..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table
{
border:0;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
font-size:10px;
font-family:Verdana;
}
#resultsCity
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
width:96px;
height:auto;
overflow:visible;
z-index:12;
text-align:center;
background:#111;
display:none;
}

#resultVenue0
{
position:relative;
top:0;
right:0;
width:96px;
min-height:60px;
height:auto;
overflow:visible;
z-index:12;
text-align:center;
background:#222;
display:block;
} 
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Form demonstration</h1>

<form action="./adduser.php" method="post" >
<table>
<tr>
    <td>User name</td>
    <td><textarea name="content" ></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Enter city or town</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="work" id='searchVenue0' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Click city</td>
<td>

<div id='resultVenue0'>
<ul id='list'></ul>
</div>

</td>
</tr>

    <td>*</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></td>

</table>


<script type='text/javascript' src='searchvenue.js'>
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

then create a file within the same directory and call it 'searchvenue.js'
you are making the ajax file that will responde to the user typing something in the CITY field

```
// file : searchvenue.js
var timer1;
var ajaxreq2;
var msg0;
var divCity0;


var array0;
ajaxreq2 = false;

var obj;
obj=document.getElementById("searchVenue0"); // form entry INPUT element
obj.onkeydown = StartSearch; // add the event that re-acts to the keyboard pressed..

divCity0 = document.getElementById("resultVenue0");

function sendmsg0(target)
{

   try 
   {
   ajaxreq2= new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   catch (error)
    {
    try {

      ajaxreq2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    } catch (error)

    {
      return false;
    }
   }

  msg0 = document.getElementById("searchVenue0").value;
  // CAPTURE the value of the TEXT in the input field
  ajaxreq2.open("POST","./searchvenue.php",true);
  ajaxreq2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  ajaxreq2.onreadystatechange = DisplayResults;
  ajaxreq2.send("msg="+msg0);

}





function StartSearch()
{

   if (timer1)
   {
    window.clearTimeout(timer1);
   }
   timer1 = window.setTimeout("sendmsg0();",200);
}


function DisplayResults() {

if (ajaxreq2.readyState !=4)
    {
        return;
    }

   if (ajaxreq2.status==200)
   {
// Create Variables

var ul,div,name,names,text,li,i,a;

   ul = document.getElementById("list");
   div = document.getElementById("resultVenue0");
   div.removeChild(ul);

   ul = document.createElement("ul");
   ul.id="list";

   names = ajaxreq2.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("name");

   for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
   {
        arrayCount = 0;
      li = document.createElement("li");
      name = names[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
      text = document.createTextNode(name);

      li.appendChild(text);
      a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = "#";



      a.appendChild(li);
      ul.appendChild(a);

   }
   if (names.length==0) {
      li = document.createElement("li");
      divCity0.style.display="none";
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("No results"));
      ul.appendChild(li);
      array0 = new Array();
      arrayCount = 0;
   }

   divCity0.style.display="block";
   div.appendChild(ul);
   }
}
```

Finally here is 'the searchvenue.php' file which the clients' browser - using ajax - will access. It will execute the php script and perform a search on the database.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$code = "";
$db = "matrix2";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$code,$db);

$sql = "SELECT city FROM citylist;";
// searching a table called citylist and getting the Column 'city'
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

$query=$_POST['msg'];
// Argument OR paramter received from the CLIENT browser
// ( the HTML input field )
echo '<?xml version="1.0" ?>';
echo "<names>";
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
{ 
   if (stristr($array['city'],$query))
    {
      echo "<name>".$array['city']."</name>";
    }
}
echo "</names>";
?>
```

the php script fetches the entire database, and only through the the use of the 'stristr' function does it filter the results, then return them via XML format to the client's request.. there should be a better sql query that could be performed.

but remember in order to test this, in the searchvenue.php script YOU MUST change the values those variables $host, $user, $code AND $db to match the database you seek to engage

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `citylist`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `citylist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `target_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `citylist` (`id`, `city`, `target_id`) VALUES
(1, 'cape town', 385095),
(2, 'durban', 295693),
(3, 'johannesburg', 886895);
```

Here is test code to create and populate the citylist table,
used in the current example

Comment: Thanks for solution but may be it's not the answer I was looking for, can U plz check the all links above in question, how many different website uses the same database to access the company details